# View apache server across virtual machine?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, apache-http-server

I installed VirtualBox on my Windows 7 machine. Through VirtualBox, I installed Ubuntu 9.10 with apache2. I can view `http://localhost` from Ubuntu, but is there anyway I can view it from my windows machine too? i.e. run the apache server on ubuntu, and view it from windows? I figured it would open a port or something that would be visible to my whole computer regardless of its virtualness, but I guess not. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://allisterx.blogspot.com/2008/05/web-server-on-virtualbox-gues-os.html

**Edit:** I should elaborate a bit. Here's the important bit from the tutorial. You need to run this on your Windows host OS.

```
cd C:\Program Files\Sun\xVM VirtualBox
VBoxManage setextradata MyLinux "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/apache/HostPort" 8888
VBoxManage setextradata MyLinux "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/apache/GuestPort" 80
VBoxManage setextradata MyLinux "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcnet/0/LUN#0/Config/apache/Protocol" TCP
```

Answer (score 1):

Open port 80 in the VM, then go to the IP address of the VM in your browser.

Comment: how do I open port 80?

Comment: I don't actually know Ubuntu well enough to be able to tell you. Take a look under `System` | `Administration`.

Comment: According to the tutorial I found, I had to do it through the host OS/Windows actually...

Answer (score 1):

While the Virtualbox is powered down, create a secondary network connection of type "host only".

Power up your Virtualbox and run `ifconfig` from the command line.

The IP address you are looking for is in the second paragraph (mine is 192.168.56.101).

---

Optional: Add the following to your Windows hosts file:

```
192.168.56.101 ubuntu
```

Now you can go straight to `http://ubuntu/`.